# How To Set ActionBar Background For Screen Orientation

Tags: android

My ActionBar code:

```
Drawable d=getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.mod);  
getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(d);
```

I just want to set my ActionBar Drawable for screen orientation. When I turn my orientation to vertical, picture expanding. I want to two codes likes as this

```
//when the screen orientation is vertical 
Drawable d=getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.mod);  
getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(d);

//when the screen orientation is horizontal 
Drawable d=getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.mod);  
getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(d);
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Override the `onConfigurationChanged` method of your activity, like this

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        Drawable d=getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.mod);  
        getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(d);
    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
        Drawable d=getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.mod);  
        getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(d);
    }
}
```

Then add the following to your android manifest

```
<activity android:name="YourActivity"
       android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
```

Comment: Getting this error: void is an invalid type for the variable onConfigurationChanged

Comment: Make sure you are putting `onConfigurationChanged` outside of any other method in your activity.

Comment: Ok there is no error. I found my wrong and fixed. But now, when I open my app, but there is no actionbar background. Note: added  android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation but still there is no background

Comment: Add `screenSize` to the `android:configChanges` as well

Comment: How? in the manifest that you changed earlier, modify the `configChanges` line to this: `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"`

Comment: No I couldnt. Is this code true?  <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
     android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:name=".ModActivity" >
        </activity>

Comment: Yeah that looks right. I tested it with those three options in `configChanges` and your code to actually set the drawable, and it worked for me

Comment: I set drawables and androidmanifest. I couldnt. Im using this code not in my MainActivity. Is the problem's source can be this?

Comment: Make sure you are adding the `configChanges` to the `Activity` tag that you are doing this in